# How can I set the speed for every person who visits my site and download from it?

Tags: server, download-speed, bandwidth, dynamic-linking, cpulimit

I installed ubuntu18 server and uploaded my own site ... How can I set the speed for every person who visits my site and download from it ???

Comment: One question mark '?' is OK, please. Welcome, @mohmedaljna. :)